# Why is my django url regex not working

Tags: regex, django

I want my url to accept 0 or more digits(positive or negative integers), I mean it should match '/','/0',...,'/9' as well as '/-9','/-88' etc.

This is the regex I am using `^([-]?[0-9]*)/$` . It works for all urls except '/', what is the problem with this regex?

**EDIT:**

This is my urlpatterns in urls.py in project directory:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('basecalendar.urls'), name='date'),
]
```

and this is urlpattern for basecalendar

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^([-]?[0-9]*)/$',views.get_date),
]
```

Comment: post the contents of `urls.py` file. May be you have assigned another view for `/` url.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have added the necessary details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with urls you might want to make sure that you are ending your url with '/'. Also, the reason why this is not working because your url is expecting a '/' at the end. So a url `something/` does not match your regex, rather `something//` does. All these observations are being made according to your regex. Usually to handle such conditions you should add one more url above your previous regex, something like:

```
url(r'^something/$', view),
url(r'^something/([-]?[0-9]*)/$', view),
```

Comment: Removing / from my current regex worked with my urlconf, now / points to '/0'

Comment: No answer for me in this text